# Grid/ smart fill but with only 3 "rails"

Tags: mesh

I have an outline that has 3 curved "segments". Actually it's all connected edges. I want to fill them with a grid that has one "pole", so it's like of 1/8 sphere but irregular.

SketchUp has a plugin called Curviloft which is very smart and handles grids like this one. It can also do stuff like Blender Grid Fill tool. I want to achieve the same result in Blender but Grid Fill tool does not help.

I know there are addons like Smart Fill and Curve to Mesh. I haven't tried them yet. Perhaps this is the way, but they are both paid, so I want to ask first.
Would you have any suggestions for me?

Thank you

[image]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1503

Comment: So your suggestion is to use curve tools? Could you show me how to do it? What I learned is that each "rail" has to be a separate curve, directions and order of selection matters too. It seems quite complicated and there are many opportunities to make a mistake. I will be trying by myself but further help I would appreciate.

Comment: Just a related method, not sure it actually works with three rails at all

Comment: I guess [Sverchok addon](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/tree/master) should be able to handle that like in [somewhat similar article](http://www.codeplastic.com/2020/01/20/parametric-wall-with-blender-and-sverchok/), in this case usage will be different though

Comment: Yes and I wanted to mark it (accept) as a solution but SE says I can only do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a workaround and it actually is described there:

[Triangular grid fill](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42960/triangular-grid-fill?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

You can have something close to what you want with a bit of tweaking with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Tool*:

Select the vertices on the 2 sides, don't select the top one:

[image]

Bridge, tweak the parameters on the *Operator* box so that it looks the way you want:

[image]

Give some corrections on the bottom and top:

[image]

Comment: Wonder if there's a way to make one  3-pole akin to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84167/whats-the-fastest-way-to-turn-a-triangular-face-into-three-quads then grid fill?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, maybe give an answer, I know mine is not completely satisfying (it works because the base is circular), there might be cleaner way

Comment: it looks like a Nurb Surface except I don't know if you can convert this into curve then into a nurb that would be filled?

Comment: I think what batFINGER means is to create a mesh which looks like bevelled corner if you bevel all edges of a cube with many segments. Perhaps this would help but I don't know how it would be achieved and my goal is to create a mesh which looks like 1/8 of a sphere.

Comment: @michalpe  Yes that was the idea, (have one 3-pole in center instead of n-pole at apex) no idea how to do it (simply) either.  Would say question is a dupe of your linked answer, (as noted by lemon)  in which case there is no need to link to and accept your answer. Instead consider accepting this answer, or moonboots consider adding this answer to that question.